# Нет доступа к открытым портам ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vds, port

Недавно столкнулся с очень странной проблемой. Сам не понял как, но закрылись все порты у VDS на ubuntu. Мне требуются 80 и 443 порты. К тому же, порт 5432 почему-то открыт.

Вывод команды `sudo lsof -bP -i | grep LISTEN`:

```html
systemd-r   360 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  16005      0t0  TCP localhost:53 (LISTEN)
sshd        792            root    3u  IPv4  20962      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        792            root    4u  IPv6  20964      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx       795            root    6u  IPv6  20981      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx       795            root    7u  IPv4  20982      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx       795            root    8u  IPv4  20983      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       795            root    9u  IPv6  20984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       796        www-data    6u  IPv6  20981      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx       796        www-data    7u  IPv4  20982      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx       796        www-data    8u  IPv4  20983      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       796        www-data    9u  IPv6  20984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       797        www-data    6u  IPv6  20981      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx       797        www-data    7u  IPv4  20982      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx       797        www-data    8u  IPv4  20983      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       797        www-data    9u  IPv6  20984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
postgres    804        postgres    3u  IPv4  21002      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres    804        postgres    4u  IPv6  21003      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
```

Вывод команды `netstat -nlp`

```html
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      795/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      795/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      360/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      792/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      804/postgres        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      795/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      795/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      792/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      804/postgres        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           360/systemd-resolve 
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     13527    1/init               /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172485   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172491   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172492   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172496   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172497   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14389    285/systemd-journal  /run/systemd/journal/io.systemd.journal
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172498   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172499   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172500   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/pk-debconf-socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     172501   8053/systemd         /run/user/0/snapd-session-agent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21004    804/postgres         /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15191    1/init               /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15193    1/init               /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15195    1/init               /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15197    1/init               /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16180    396/irqbalance       /run/irqbalance//irqbalance396.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13500    1/init               /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13502    1/init               /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13513    1/init               /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13523    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
```

Подскажите, что такого могло произойти и как это исправить?

Comment: Что даёт `sudo ufw status`? Вторая мысль - порты закрыл хостер VDS-ов. Были от хостера письма?

Comment: @PakUula выдает `Status: inactive`

Comment: @PakUula письм от хостера не было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось самому решить проблему.
Перед тем как появилась проблема, был установлен firewalld, после чего все порты закрылись.

Для решения есть несколько способов:

1. Настроить файервол
2. Отключить сервис файервола командами:

> ```
> sudo systemctl stop firewalld
> sudo systemctl disable firewalld
> ```

3. Удалить его, если не нужен: `sudo apt remove firewalld`

Comment: вряд ли файрвол сам установился, верно же? А вы его загасили. Вначале так же было про "порт 5432 почему-то открыт", судя по приведенным данным там Постгрес (который тоже не сам поставился). Т.е. у вас какая-то несогласованность действий с командой (?) по управлению VDS. Само же оно не может устанавливаться и т.п. И наверняка файрвол зачем-то был поставлен? Может лучше уточнить кем и сконфигурировать его как нужно?

Comment: @Дмитрий Я восстановил хронологию своих действий. Моей начальной целью было открыть порт 5432, который слушал постргес. Для этого по инструкции в интернете я скачал файервол и открыл этот порт. Далее, на следующий день я уже забыл про это, и заметил, что все порты закрыты,кроме 5432. Долго не мог разобраться почему, и даже не смотрел на файервол. Уже после того как задал этот вопрос тут, я смог разобраться и убрал ненужный мне файервол.

Comment: Ясно ))) Но если честно я бы не хотел чтобы у меня БД торчала в дикий интернет открыто

Comment: @Дмитрий Да это уж понятно. Проблема тут заключалась в другом. К БД сто процентов надо ограничивать доступ по ssh или по ip

Comment: А что мешает настроить Пострес слушать только 127.0.0.1, раз у вас приложение на одном хосте с базой? А ходить к нему снаружи (при надобности) вы можете через ssh-тоннель

Comment: @Дмитрий Мне ничего не мешает. VDS сервер у меня не продовский. Предназначен для тестов и разработки. А потому с его защитой не заморачиваюсь